# Stone Weierstrass problem, showing equivalence between subsets of $C(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space containing at least two points and let $A$ be a proper, closed sub algebra of $C(X)$.  I want to prove that if $A$ separates points in $X $then there is $x_0$ in $X$ such that $A = \{f \in C(x): f(x_0) = 0\}$.

I have proved $A$ is a subset of $\{f \in C(x): f(x_0) = 0\}$. I have also proved that $x_0$ is unique. I am having trouble showing reverse inclusion.

I can show it for any compact subset of $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ but I don't know how to deal with $x_0$, the functions of $A$ may be poorly behaved at $x_0$.

Comment: This is might be a late comment but I guess you may want $A$ to be self-adjoint as well if $C(X)$ means all continuous complex-valued functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=\{c\cdot 1+f:c\in\mathbb{C},f\in A\}$ and use Stone-Weierstrass to show that $B$ is all of $C(X)$.  The reverse inclusion you're trying to prove then follows, since if $g=c\cdot 1+f$ for $f\in A$ and $g(x_0)=0$ then $c=0$.